# In JavaScript, when we declare a variable and use a DOM method to get an element, is this assign-by-reference?

Tags: javascript, variables

I was reviewing the type of value assigned to a variable which determines whether the value is stored with assign-by-value or assign-by-reference.

I understand that:

A. Assign-by-value: For scalar primitive values (e.g., a number), when a value is assigned from one variable to another, a new copy of the value is created. Modifications to the copied value do not affect the original.

B. Assign-by-reference: For compound values (e.g., an array), when a value is assigned from one variable to another, they point to the same, shared value. Modifications to the shared value affect all variables pointing to it.

However, I can't find any article that mentions the DOM method for example:

let mySearchIcon = document.querySelector(".search-icon");

Could you please confirm that the variable mySearchIcon isn't holding the HTML element itself, but rather it is holding a reference to the HTML element? So is this "assign-by-reference"?

Please excuse my ignorance and I appreciate your input.

Comment: "compound values" - we call them "objects" :-) And yes, the document object model gives you HTML element objects.

Comment: One could also shorten it to ... Everything is a reference except for [primitive values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) like boolean, number and string values, bigint and symbol values as well as null and undefined values. All of these are immutable values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input.  Is pass-by-value the same as assign-by-value?